# Отобразить изображение в Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть ссылки на изображения в ячейках. Я бы хотел сделать какое-то отображение изображения при наведении на ссылку или при нажатии на какую-то ячейку, что-то вроде всплывающего окна. Возможно ли это?

Я перечитал документацию, вроде как нет возможности запустить какой-то скрипт при нажатии на ячейку. Я пробовал создавать Sidebar для отображения изображения там, но это не удобно, так как нужно нажимать сначала на ссылку с изображением и потом вручную открывать Sidebar через меню. Это не удобно, было бы удобнее если бы скрипт можно было запустить просто по нажатию на ячейку.

Comment: Подойдёт ли Вам вариант, когда Вы в той же строке нажимаете соседнюю ячейку (скажем, чекбокс в ней)  и получаете в назначенной ячейке (можно - в той же строке, но необязательно) изображение заданных размеров?

Comment: Я не хочу чтобы каждая строка была растянута из-за картинок. У меня есть Sidebar, может туда можно запихнуть? Мне главное сделать чтобы при нажатии на ячейку скрипт выполнялся, но это не так просто сделать, так как нет никакого onClick на ячейке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё же рискну предложить решение, основанное на чекбоксах, потому что никакими кликами по обычной ячейке обработчик скрипта нам не вызвать. С другой стороны, переключение чекбокса прекрасно ловится [устанавливаемыми триггерами типа "Edit"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Нам потребуется именно устанавливаемый (installable) триггер, так как он справляется с отображением сайд-баров. Обычному простому триггеру "onEdit" такие действия запрещены.

Итак, для следующей функции надо установить триггер "Edit":

```
function onUserEdit(e) {
  var rule = e.range.getDataValidation();
  if (rule != null && rule.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
    var imageUrl = e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue();
    var img = '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />';
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page').append(img)
    .setTitle('My image preview').setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    e.range.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Она будет срабатывать лишь при изменении значений чекбоксов, так как делается соответствующая проверка на наличие валидатора данного типа.
После отображения картинки на сайд-баре чекбокс сразу же очищается, так как его задача уже выполнена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрел, там вроде бы есть какой-то триггер который срабатывает по времени. Получается я могу просто проверять каждую секунду изменилась ли ячейка и если изменилась и в ней ссылка на картинку то открывать картинку в Sidebar? Будет что-то вроде срабатывания скрипта при нажатии на ячеку.

Comment: Триггер по времени на стороне сервера есть, но не чаще раза в минуту. А вот клиентский - внутри сайд-бара - он же setTimeout - это пожалуйста, хоть каждую секунду. Тогда надо использовать [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) для получения информации о текущей ячейке. Мне такой способ нравится меньше, так нагрузка на сервер заметно возрастает.

Comment: Не подскажете как мне отобразить в Sidebar PDF файл? Изображение понятно, но PDF не получается. Проблема еще в том, что ссылка вида
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10H6JqblrM8OKIrSvvH90cFJZns1WmtRx или 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10H6JqblrM8OKIrSvvH90cFJZns1WmtRx/view

Comment: <embed src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" type="application/pdf"   height="700px" width="500"> почему-то не работает, не отображается

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1uL8sd2y/

Comment: Обратите внимание, Ваши ссылки ведут не прямо к PDF документам, а к странице их просмотра. Значит, писать `type="application/pdf"`, мягко говоря, не правильно. Если сможете отделить чистый PDF контент, то уже можно попробовать варианты: https://codepen.io/Ranjithkumar10/pen/PGogxW или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page

Comment: Да, я знаю что ссылки не ведут к PDF. В том то и проблема. Ваш пример не работает с этими ссылками. Получается возможности такой нет?

Comment: У меня нет простых рецептов для этого. А сложные нет смысла пересказывать. Возможно, что-то подскажут другие участники.

Comment: Большое спасибо что потратили на меня время и помогли.

Comment: Можете дать линк на документ гугл таблицы, что бы наглядно посмотреть?
У меня почему то скрипт не заработал :(

Comment: Мой документ не сохранился, сорри. Проверьте правильность установки триггера (сократите код, чтобы только видеть, что триггер работает). Затем поэтапно добавляйте нужный код, чтобы понять где именно он не работает и почему. У меня все работало как написано.